# How to get emoji from message reference

Tags: reference, discord.py, emoji

ref = ctx.message.reference

```
    msg = await ctx.fetch_message(ref.message_id)



    hmm = msg.emojis

    for emoji in hmm:

        S = await emoji.fetch()

    imgOrGif = BytesIO(await S.read())

    bValue = imgOrGif.getvalue()

    await ctx.guild.create_custom_emoji(name="prince",image=bValue)
```

I'm getting error message object has no attribute emoji

I want to know how to get emoji from message reference and steal that emoji

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/f4m657/discordpy_get_all_emojis_on_user_message/ to see how to get the emojies from a message. I don't think there is a direct way to get emojies from a message like how you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to find all custom emojis in a message:

```py
import re


EMOJI_REGEX = r'<(?P<animated>a?):(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]{2,32}):(?P<id>[0-9]{18,22})>'


async def my_comamnd(ctx):
    ref = ctx.message.reference
    msg = await ctx.fetch_message(ref.message_id)
    emojis = re.findall(EMOJI_REGEX, msg.content)
```

`emojis` will be a list in the format `[(animated, name, id), ...]`. Example:

```py
[('', 'Nitro', '687755198579343374'), ('a', 'aSDVemotequestion', '1008463027881910335'), ...]
```

Keep in mind that to use these emojis, your bot needs to be on their origin server.
If you want to steal these emojis, you can get the emoji image link from its id:

```py
from aiohttp import ClientSession


for emoji in emojis:
    name = emoji[1]
    ext = "gif" if emoji[0] else "png"
    image_url = f"https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/{emoji[2]}.{ext}"

    # download the image
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(image_url) as resp:
            image = await resp.read()

    await ctx.guild.create_custom_emoji(name=name, image=image)
```

> Note: this regex will only find custom emojis (those that are created by servers). Standard Discord emojis have a different format and are not captured by this regex.

Comment: Why bot can't create animated emoji?

Comment: Oh, for animated emojis we need to change `.png` to `.gif` in the image link

Comment: for both ? Animated and png

Comment: Fixed the code to support animated emojis too

Comment: Thanku  if you don't mind can I have ur discord?

Comment: My discord is Hazzu#0707

Comment: Thank you  my discord Prince?#2424